# A regex to split a text string in R

Tags: r, regex

I have a very long string like this sample bellow and I'm struggling to find a regex to split it in parts according to the patern, for example: '1. OAS / AC' and '2. OAS / AD'.

This slice of text has:

1) a varying number in the beginning

2) two capital letters varying from A to Z

I tried this:

```
x <- stringr::str_split(have, "([1-9])( OAS / )([A-Z]{2})")
```

but not works

Thanks in advance, for any help!

Example

```
require(stringr)
have <- "1. OAS / AC 12345/this is a test string to regex, 2. OAS / AD     79856/this is another test string to regex, 3. OAS / AE 87987/this is a new test string to regex. 4. OAS / AZ 78798456/this is one mode test string to regex."
want <- stringr::str_split(have, "([1-9])( OAS / )([A-Z]{2})")

want <- list(
         "1. OAS / AC " = "12345/this is a test string to regex,",
         "2. OAS / AD " = "79856/this is another test string to regex,",
         "3. OAS / AE " = "87987/this is a new test string to regex.",
         "4. OAS / AZ " = "78798456/this is one mode test string to regex."
)
```

Comment: Try `stringr::str_match_all(have, "(\\d+\\. OAS / [A-Z]{2})\\s*(.*?)(?=\\s*\\d+\\. OAS / [A-Z]{2}|\\z)")`

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew. I was far from getting such a solution. Thanks a lot for the help.

Answer (score 1):

We could do this with a positive lookahead, looking for the pattern of a number, followed by a peroid:

```
str_split(have, "(?=\\d+\\.)")

[1] ""                                                             "1. OAS / AC 12345/this is a test string to regex, "          
[3] "2. OAS / AD     79856/this is another test string to regex, " "3. OAS / AE 87987/this is a new test string to regex. "      
[5] "4. OAS / AZ 78798456/this is one mode test string to regex."
```

And we can further clean it up:

```
str_split(have, "(?=\\d{1,2}\\.)") %>% unlist() %>% .[-1]

[1] "1. OAS / AC 12345/this is a test string to regex, "           "2. OAS / AD     79856/this is another test string to regex, "
[3] "3. OAS / AE 87987/this is a new test string to regex. "       "4. OAS / AZ 78798456/this is one mode test string to regex."
```

Comment: Hi @Mako212 . Thank you so much for your help. That will help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
library(stringr)
have <- "1. OAS / AC 12345/this is a test string to regex, 2. OAS / AD     79856/this is another test string to regex, 3. OAS / AE 87987/this is a new test string to regex. 4. OAS / AZ 78798456/this is one mode test string to regex."
r <- stringr::str_match_all(have, "(\\d+\\. OAS / [A-Z]{2})\\s*(.*?)(?=\\s*\\d+\\. OAS / [A-Z]{2}|\\z)")
res <- r[[1]][,3]
names(res) <- r[[1]][,2]
```

Result:

```
dput(res)
# => structure(c("12345/this is a test string to regex,", "79856/this is another test string to regex,", 
#  "87987/this is a new test string to regex.", "78798456/this is one mode test string to regex."
#  ), .Names = c("1. OAS / AC", "2. OAS / AD", "3. OAS / AE", "4. OAS / AZ"
#  ))
```

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/W4B7ny/1).

**Pattern details**

- `(\d+\. OAS / [A-Z]{2})` - Capturing group 1:

  - `\d+` - 1+ digits
  - `\.` - a `.`
  - `OAS /`  - a literal  `OAS /`  substring
  - `[A-Z]{2}` - two uppercase letters
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `(.*?)` - Capturing group 2: any 0+ chars other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?=\s*\d+\. OAS / [A-Z]{2}|\z)` - a positive lookahead: immediately to the right of the current location, there must

  - `\s*\d+\. OAS / [A-Z]{2}` - 0+ whitespaces, 1+ digits, `.`, space, `/`, space, two uppercase letters
  - `|` - or
  - `\z` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

They way you described the issue is kinda unclear, but if you want to simply extract till `"OAS / AC"`,

```
library(qdap)
beg2char(have, " ", 4)#looks for the fourth occurrence of \\s and extracts everything before it.
```

For the above function to work, the sentences should be individual strings in a character vector

If your aim is to actually insert an `"="` sign between the two letter sub-string and the number occurring after `"OAS"`,

```
gsub("([A-Z])\\s*([0-9])","\\1 = \\2",have,perl=T)
```